# Is there a way to fix this scrape issue?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Iam trying to do price checker for something and tried to run this code but it didn't give me everything and i got suspended on the site for like 10 hours for sending too much commands is there a way to fix it or i just cant scrape that much pages at once?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5"}

skinlist = []
def getskins(page):
    url = f'https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730#p{page}_popular_desc'
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    sm = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'market_listing_row')
    for item in sm:
        skin = {
        'title': item.find('span', class_ = 'market_listing_item_name').text,
        'price': item.find('span', class_ = 'normal_price').text,
        }
        skinlist.append(skin)
    return

for x in range(1,1633):
    getskins(x)

print(len(skinlist))
```

Comment: You'll need to add a timer to hit the site every so often (i.e. 5-10 minutes), looping through 1633 iterations immediately will _definitely_ get you blocked, as you've experienced.

Comment: Try retrieving the json itself. Mess around with this url
`https://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?query=&start=1490&count=10&search_descriptions=0&sort_column=price&sort_dir=desc&appid=730&norender=1`

Answer (score 0):

if you didn't have requests limitation you could use `threading` library to send a lot of requests together.

what you can do now?

you can search for api endpoint to take the info from or try to understand how the website take the info and do the same